# Some M4 macros don't seem to be defined

Tags: compiling, autoconf

I am trying reinstall pacman on my Arch Linux distribution. When I run the configure script "configure.ac", I get a bunch of undefined macros:

```
error: possibly undefined macro: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE.
If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
See the autoconf documentation.
error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
error: possibly undefined macro: AM_GNU_GETTEXT 
error: possibly undefined macro: AM_GNU_GETTEXT_VERSION
error: possibly undefined macro: AM_CONDITIONAL
```

Does anyone know what would cause these macros to be undefined? Having come from Ubuntu (where everything just works, and is therefore boring), I don't really know about automake.

Comment: Why are you building from source? Why don't you download the packages on another machine, copy them across and extract them to root as per https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Q:_pacman_is_completely_broken.21_How_do_I_reinstall_it.3F

Comment: It appears that what? Is that the whole sequence of errors? How did you retrieve the source?

Comment: Jason, I do not have pacman on my other machine, and I would rather not download another package manager. Plus if I was not building from source I would not have this wonderful opportunity to learn about M4 and automake. Sorry about the bad edit, I removed it. Yes, that is the whole sequence of errors. I retrieved the source from the ArchLinux website at projects.archlinux.org/pacman.git with wget.

Comment: configure.ac is not a configure script and is not runnable.

Answer (score 87):

Try this, maybe it can help:

```
autoreconf --install
```

(See the manpage, there is a `--force` option also)

Comment: cvs program not found; autopoint failed with exit status 1. I am installing cvs from sources, will let you know how it goes.

Comment: @SirTasty: cvs?? hmm, maybe try to use `autoconf` and `automake` directly?

Comment: Autoconf gives me the undefined macro warnings. automake gives me (semicolons separate lines):

`Makefile.am:2: WANT_DOC does not appear in AM_CONDITIONAL`
;
`Makefile.am: required file ./ChangeLog not found
;
`configure.ac:57: required file config.h.in not found`

Comment: I'm not an autotools expert (or fan either). Maybe wait for one to show up… By chance, what about `aclocal` first?

Comment: I had a similar autoconf error (on redhat fc19) and the autoreconf --install solved it.

Comment: might require sudo apt-get install autopoint

Comment: This worked for me with the exact same set of errors as in the original question.

Comment: stackoverflow.com concurs with your solution (use `autoreconf --install`): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999549/how-do-i-create-a-configure-script

Comment: i'm not sure why but i saw somewhere on google someone suggesting to use `autoconf` to generate the `configure` script. of course i saw this on a website that doesn't have vetting/peer-review and so that is probably why i saw it.

Answer (score 30):

The macros in the error message you posted are defined by [automake](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/any/automake/) and [libtool](http://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/i686/libtool/); it looks like you need to install those packages.

Then try `autoreconf --install`

Comment: Both of those packages are installed, or at least "which automake" and "which libtool" return reasonable results.

Comment: @SirTasty Then you probably need to run "autoreconf" as Stéphane suggests.

Comment: On my CentOS6.7 system, I had to do this: `sudo yum install autoconf automake libtool cmake autoconf-archive gcc-c++`

Comment: For me, with the error `configure.ac:118: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_MSG_ERROR` on Manjaro Linux, installing `autoconf-archive` did the trick, although another error resulted which has also now been avoided. The other packages were installed. Just for information, further details on that start from https://github.com/NixOS/nix/pull/3154#issuecomment-545207139/.

Answer (score 9):

For anybody else looking: While automake and libtool are very likely candidates, some systems won't install gettext automatically. This is also required.

Answer (score 5):

Install following packages that would solve the autoreconf issues.

```
$ sudo apt-get -y install autoconf automake libtool cmake autoconf-archive build-essential
```

Answer (score 3):

I was pretty confused when getting these errors, because I had everything installed and autoreconf --install wasn't helping. The problem was just corrupted aclocal.m4 and deleting it before autoreconf solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The aclocal.m4 needs to be generated first. `aclocal` generates the aclocal.m4 file based on the contents of configure.ac

```
libtoolize --force
aclocal
autoheader
automake --force-missing --add-missing
autoconf
./configure
```